# Remove all duplicates and undefined in arrays. Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a such data structure:

```
{
  '123': [1,1,3,2,undefined],
  '321': [3,3,3,2,undefined,undefined],
  '425': [null,2,2,4,2,null,null]
}
```

I want to add item to group array and then check for undefined or duplicates exist.
I also have a solution but I think it's not good enough:

**`check-is-nil.js`**

```
const checkIsNil = (groupId, data) => {
  return over(lensProp(groupId), pipe(reject(isNil),uniq), data);
}
```

**`add-to-group.js`**

```
const addToGroup = (groupId, newObj, data) => {
  return over(lensProp(groupId), append(newObj), data);
};
```

**Using:**
`checkIsNil('123', addToGroup('123', 1, data))`
**Result:**

```
{
  '123': [1,3,2],
  '321': [3,2],
  '425': [2,4]
}
```

Comment: Since this solution works and you're looking for improvements, consider posting on [codereview.se]. Please do check the guidelines for what is acceptable over there and tailor the question appropriately.

Comment: @VLAZ, I'm not sure I can get the answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reject is nil` should do the job, you could eventually use `value => value === undefined` if you want to keep `null` values.

```js
const clean = R.map(
  R.pipe(R.reject(R.isNil), R.uniq),
);

const data = {
  '123': [1,1,3,2,undefined],
  '321': [3,3,3,2,undefined,undefined],
  '425': [null,2,2,4,2,null,null]
};


console.log(
  clean(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```